# Convergence w.p. 1 vs convergence in probability: a "physical" example

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question

I understand (proved) that convergence with probability one implies convergence in probability, and that the latter notion is indeed weaker; I've completed an exercise showing that a sequence of indicator variables on $[0,1]$ converged in probability but not almost everywhere.

However, I still don't have intuition about these notions of convergence in the "real world". Is there an example using either coin tossing or some concrete physical process such that by using plain english, it is obvious that we have convergence in probability, but not convergence almost everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a lightbulb which is being replaced each time it goes broken and assume that the lifetime of the $n$th lightbulb used is exponential (as lightbulbs lifetimes often are, at least in mathematics, aren't they?) with mean $\mu_n=n$. Let $D_t$ denote the age of the lightbulb in use at time $t$, that is, $t-D_t$ denotes the time at which the lightbulb in use at time $t$ began to be used.

Then $[D_t\to\infty]$ has probability zero since $D_t=0$ at every time $t$ in  the unbounded sequence of time replacements. But  $P(D_t\geqslant x)\to1$ for every $x$ because $\mu_n\to\infty$ hence $D_t\to\infty$ in probability.

If infinities are a problem, note that $X_t=1/D_t$ is such that $X_t\to0$ in probability but not almost surely.